# Android: use Espresso 2.0 on Eclipse to use onData with CursorAdapter. Possible?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-espresso

For Android coding, I am stuck with Eclipse for now (dependencies) in stead of Android Studio.

So far, I have used Google Espresso 1.1, but while using an onData-based test with a CursorAdapter I get the exact same error message as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/ZLqEFJng81o.

I have modified my code to compile with Espresso 2.0 but at runtime Dagger gives me an NoSuchMethodError like [Dagger throw a NoSuchMethodException when creating the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268406/dagger-throw-a-nosuchmethodexception-when-creating-the-graph).

I'd appreciate advice on how to proceed, or a definite "can't be done" answer.

Comment: It takes seconds to switch to Android Studio. You can literally copy and paste the `AndroidManifest.xml`, `.java` source files and all of your `res` resources into an Android Studio project.